# AirPrint for ios Adobe air native extension .ane

Tags: ios

Im tryin to create a native extension to allow to send bytearray "png" 
and print it through AirPrint.

Has anyone tried that? i mean the bytearray. Or at least maybe send a path to a local image 
save in documents.

Any help or guidance i smuch appreciated from anyone with good IOS knowledge as im just starting.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried any printing, but you can take a look at 
http://sugartin.info/2012/02/02/ios-print-functionality-to-print-using-airprinter/
where you have an example of sending UIImage to airprinter.
To pass bitmapdata from as3 to ios (and get uiimage with your graphic), you can check my attempt at https://github.com/memeller/ContactEditor/blob/master/ContactEditorXCode/ContactEditor.m
(look for setContactImage function, line 655)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/janumedia/AirPrintANE/ is available to print from bitmapdata